# Java - ArrayList method for a sublist including the last element?

Tags: java, arraylist, sublist

For a sublist of an `ArrayList`, how do I get the sublist including the last element in the list? If I'm using the wrong method, can you direct me towards the correct one?

```
list.subList(startIndex, index + list.size()) // obviously doesn't work, outside of range
list.sublist(startIndex) // doesn't work because this method requires two parameters
```

Comment: passing `list.size()` as the second parameter will give you every element from the beginning index to the end. So `list.sublist(0, list.size())` will return the complete original list.

Comment: `sublist` is exclusiv, so `list.subList(startIndex, list.size())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the correct method including a description in the JavaDoc:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractList.html#subList(int,int)

```
public List<E> subList(int fromIndex,
                       int toIndex)
```

With this method, you can create a new list including all the elements from an existing list, you want to have in your new list.

Example: `final var newList = oldList.subList(7, oldList.size());`

This will create a new list containing the objects from position 8 to the end of the old list.

Comment: You're right, thanks. Must be another problem with my code giving the index out of range exception, as the method allows lastIndex + 1... Thanks for taking the time to answer as I'm just starting out...

Comment: Do you know how debugging works? You can go step by step through your running program, line by line, and see exactly what every single line does. You should debug your application and I'm pretty sure you will find the root of your problem.